# Не могу передать значение из дочернего компонента в родительский

Tags: javascript, reactjs, события, jsx

Сейчас я пытаюсь добиться  следующего поведения: при выборе определенного человека, что бы он добавлялся в состояние `selectedMentor`. Сейчас `selectedMentor` хранит `null`.

Часть кода родительского компонента `HourlyRates`:

```
const HourlyRates = () => {
  const [workers,setworkers] = useState(null)
  const [mentorsFromMoodle, setMentorsFromMoodle] = useState(null)
  const [modalActive,setModalActive] = useState(false)
  const [selectedMentor, setSelectedMentor] = useState(null)
  useEffect(()=>{

   
  const handleSelectedMentor = (mentor) => {
    console.log(mentor)
    setSelectedMentor(mentor);
    console.log("родитель")
    console.log(selectedMentor)
  };

  return (
    <>
        
        <Modal active={modalActive} setModalActive={setModalActive}>

          <div onClick={e=> e.stopPropagation()}>

          <label for="cars">Choose a mentor:</label>
            <select onChange={handleSelectedMentor} name="mentors" id="mentors-select">
              {mentorsFromMoodle?.map((item,index) =>(
                  <ModalRow
                  key = {index}
                  index = {index}
                  item = {item}
                  onSelect = {handleSelectedMentor}
                />
                  ) )
              }
            </select>
            <button >add</button>

          </div>
          </Modal>

    </>
  )
}

export default HourlyRates;
```

Дочерний элемент `ModalRow` :

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import { useState,useEffect} from 'react'
const ModalRow = (props) => {

  const handleMentorClick = () => {
    console.log("работает")
    const mentorName = props.item.firstname;
    const mentorLastname = props.item.lastname;
    const mentorEmail = props.item.email;
    const mentor = {fname: mentorName, lname: mentorLastname, mentorEmail: mentorEmail };
    
    props.onSelect(mentor)
  };
  
  return (
    <option onChange={() => handleMentorClick()}   className={"modalRowId-" + props.index} value={props.item.email}>{props.item.firstname}  {props.item.lastname}</option>
  )
}

export default ModalRow
```

Comment: У вас здесь случайно в конце не лишние `()`? `onChange={() => handleMentorClick()}`

Comment: @OliverPatterson Там все норм. Создается на событие анонимная функция которая как раз вызывает фукнцию. тут ок.

Comment: Мне кажется, этот ответ для вас, почему там пусто - [Почему не отображаются данные после установки состояния](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1504680/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82/1504690#1504690). Чисто визуально, ваш код правильный

Comment: @SwaD, там вызывает функция при создании, а не при клике) Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @OliverPatterson Я немного стормозил... `option onChange` у option нет такого события. Срабатывает событие `select onChange`, однако в функцию параметры не передаются. Надо бы проверить конечно на всякий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В **HourlyRates** <
Меняете тело функции на получение события onSelect и выбранного значения

```
const handleSelectedMentor = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setSelectedMentor(mentorsFromMoodle[event.target.value]);
    console.log("родитель")
    console.log(mentorsFromMoodle[event.target.value])
};
```

Удаляете **onSelect** из передачи в компонент **ModalRow**

```
<ModalRow
    key={index}
    index={index}
    item={item}
/>
```

В компоненте **ModalRow** Удаляете функцию **handleMentorClick** и слушатель события **onChange**
В качестве **value** вместо `value={props.item.email}` задаем индекс элемента `value={props.index}`

```
<option className={"modalRowId-" + props.index} value={props.index}>{props.item.firstname}  {props.item.lastname}</option>
```

И работает!

При смене options будет передан id индекса массива, по которому данные будут добавлены в переменную `selectedMentor`